# MySQL COUNT in LEFT JOIN WHERE

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, left-join, where-clause

I'm not an expert, keep this in mind please when answering my question...
I've read many other examples about here on stackoverflow, but I simply don't understand how to use it with my task.

I got an Album database table, and a Photo database table:

table_album:

```
album_id   album_creatoruser_id
-------------------------------
   1           777
   2           777
   3           777
```

table_photos:

```
photo_id   photo_album_id
-------------------------
   1            1
   2            1
   3            1
   4            1
   5            2
   6            2
   7            3
   8            3
   9            3
```

Now I'd like to get the sum of all photos, created by a user, in my example `album_creatoruser_id=777`

I'm sure it would be possible directly in MySQL, with one query or subqueries, or with LEFT JOIN or GROUP BY, but I can't get it working because I don't understand the logic to build up this query.

Any help how to count the `photo_id` rows for all `album_id`'s a specific `album_creatoruser_id` has created would be nice!

In short: How many photos **album_creatoruser_id 777** got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic query is:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM table_album ta
     JOIN table_photo tp
       ON tp.photo_album_id = ta.album_id     
    WHERE album_creatoruser_id = **input**
```

I suggest running the following queries in order to find out how it works:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM table_album ta
     JOIN table_photo tp
       ON tp.photo_album_id = ta.album_id
```

Would return all rows from `table_album` with their respective `table_photo` records under the condition `tp.photo_album_id = ta.album_id`.

```
   SELECT *
     FROM table_album ta
     JOIN table_photo tp
       ON tp.photo_album_id = ta.album_id
    WHERE album_creatoruser_id = **input**
```

Filters these rows to only those where `album_creatoruser_id = **input**`.

```
   SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM table_album ta
     JOIN table_photo tp
       ON tp.photo_album_id = ta.album_id
    WHERE album_creatoruser_id = **input**
```

Counts up these rows, returning one aggregated row (`COUNT()` is an aggregate function like `SUM()` or `MAX()`) with the result, you don't need `GROUP BY` because there is only one group; all the filtered rows.

If you want all `album_creatoruser_id`s with their respective counts I would suggest:

```
   SELECT album_creatoruser_id, COUNT(*)
     FROM table_album ta
     JOIN table_photo tp
       ON tp.photo_album_id = ta.album_id
 GROUP BY album_creatoruser_id
```

Answer (score 1):

first possibility with subquery, count of all photo created by user 777:

```
 SELECT 
      COUNT(*)
 FROM photo
 WHERE
      photo_album_id IN 
      (
           SELECT album_id 
           FROM album 
           WHERE album_creatoruser_id = 777
      )
```

other:

```
 SELECT 
     COUNT(*)
 FROM photo p, album a
 WHERE 
     p.photo_album_id = a.album_id 
     AND a.album_creatoruser_id = 777
```

and with join

```
 SELECT 
      COUNT(*)
 FROM photo p 
 JOIN album a
 ON p.photo_album_id = a.album_id     
 WHERE 
      a.album_creatoruser_id = 777
```

Grouping here is not necessary, because We don't want present the data in groups.

Comment: A note to the OP, I would only ever use the last one of these.. the first one is slower and the second one is a filtered CROSS JOIN which is hard to read in all but the simplest queries. You actually don't need the LEFT on the LEFT JOIN because COUNT(*) will return 0 in the case of no rows.

Comment: Yes you are right. But you wrote, "I'm sure it would be possible directly in MySQL...", so that's why I wanted to help on a variety of examples. First question is realy slow.. don't use it. (because, this question creating temporary table.)